# locked value of activity in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I import project from Github into Android Studio. but when change values or edit codes let me not allow access!!!! 
Please show Error image : [Click to see](http://si.uploads.im/1muza.jpg)

how to fix it ?

AppIntroi Codes :

```
public abstract class AppIntro extends FragmentActivity {
private AppIntro.PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;
private ViewPager pager;
private List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector();
private List<ImageView> dots;
private int slidesNumber;
boolean showSkip = true;

public AppIntro() {
}

protected final void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(1);
    this.getWindow().setFlags(1024, 1024);
    this.setContentView(layout.intro_layout);
    final TextView skip = (TextView)this.findViewById(id.skip);
    final ImageView next = (ImageView)this.findViewById(id.next);
    final TextView done = (TextView)this.findViewById(id.done);
    skip.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AppIntro.this.onSkipPressed();
        }
    });
    next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AppIntro.this.pager.setCurrentItem(AppIntro.this.pager.getCurrentItem() + 1);
        }
    });
    done.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AppIntro.this.onDonePressed();
        }
    });
    this.mPagerAdapter = new AppIntro.PagerAdapter(super.getSupportFragmentManager(), this.fragments);
    this.pager = (ViewPager)this.findViewById(id.view_pager);
    this.pager.setAdapter(this.mPagerAdapter);
    this.pager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        }

        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            AppIntro.this.selectDot(position);
            if(position == AppIntro.this.slidesNumber - 1) {
                skip.setVisibility(4);
                next.setVisibility(8);
                done.setVisibility(0);
            } else {
                skip.setVisibility(0);
                done.setVisibility(8);
                next.setVisibility(0);
            }

            if(!AppIntro.this.showSkip) {
                skip.setVisibility(4);
            }

        }

        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
        }
    });
    this.init(savedInstanceState);
    this.loadDots();
    this.selectDot(0);
}

private void loadDots() {
    LinearLayout dotLayout = (LinearLayout)this.findViewById(id.dotLayout);
    this.dots = new ArrayList();
    this.slidesNumber = this.fragments.size();

    for(int i = 0; i < this.slidesNumber; ++i) {
        ImageView dot = new ImageView(this);
        dot.setImageDrawable(this.getResources().getDrawable(drawable.indicator_dot_grey));
        LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(-2, -2);
        dotLayout.addView(dot, params);
        this.dots.add(dot);
    }

}

public void selectDot(int idx) {
    Resources res = this.getResources();

    for(int i = 0; i < this.fragments.size(); ++i) {
        int drawableId = i == idx?drawable.indicator_dot_white:drawable.indicator_dot_grey;
        Drawable drawable = res.getDrawable(drawableId);
        ((ImageView)this.dots.get(i)).setImageDrawable(drawable);
    }

}

public void addSlide(Fragment fragment, Context context) {
    this.fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(context, fragment.getClass().getName()));
    this.mPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void setBarColor(int color) {
    LinearLayout bottomBar = (LinearLayout)this.findViewById(id.bottom);
    bottomBar.setBackgroundColor(color);
}

public void setSeparatorColor(int color) {
    TextView separator = (TextView)this.findViewById(id.bottom_separator);
    separator.setBackgroundColor(color);
}

public void showSkipButton(boolean showButton) {
    this.showSkip = showButton;
    if(!showButton) {
        TextView skip = (TextView)this.findViewById(id.skip);
        skip.setVisibility(4);
    }

}

public abstract void init(Bundle var1);

public abstract void onSkipPressed();

public abstract void onDonePressed();

public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private List<Fragment> fragments;

    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager this$0, List<Fragment> fm) {
        super(fm);
        this.fragments = fragments;
    }

    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return (Fragment)this.fragments.get(position);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return this.fragments.size();
    }
}
```

R.java Codes :

```
public final class R {
public static final class drawable {
    public static final int ic_navigate_next_white_24dp = 0x7f020038;
    public static final int indicator_dot_grey = 0x7f020039;
    public static final int indicator_dot_white = 0x7f02003a;
}
public static final class id {
    public static final int bottom = 0x7f090048;
    public static final int bottom_separator = 0x7f090049;
    public static final int done = 0x7f09004d;
    public static final int dotLayout = 0x7f09004b;
    public static final int next = 0x7f09004c;
    public static final int test = 0x7f09004a;
    public static final int view_pager = 0x7f090047;
}
public static final class layout {
    public static final int intro_layout = 0x7f04001b;
}
```

MainActivity Codes :

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppIntro {
    @Override
    public void init(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        addSlide(new FirstSlide(), getApplicationContext());
        addSlide(new SecondSlide(), getApplicationContext());

        setBarColor(Color.parseColor("#3F51B5"));
        setSeparatorColor(Color.parseColor("#2196F3"));
        showSkipButton(false);
    }

    private void loadMainActivity() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSkipPressed() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onDonePressed() {
        loadMainActivity();
    }

    public void getStarted(View v) {
        loadMainActivity();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are trying to change the compiled .class files. You can only change the .java files . AppIntro.java is from some external library and because the latest version of android studio has decompiler by default , you are able to see the readable version of the file. If you want to change AppIntro , extend it and right your own version

```
public class MyActivity extends AppIntro {
      //your changes
}
```

Comment: Thank you dear friend. But is there any way to change it? It is very important for me

Comment: its a abstrac class. write your own activity extending it

Comment: tnx dear friend, Do I put the source code can tell the class how changes in the main activity?

Comment: yeah go ahead and post your changes

Comment: very thanks you <3. my post has update. i will change Done and Skip text and if possible set the marginBottom for layout. but Done and Skip text important for me

Comment: what is the issue you are facing

Comment: i will change Done and Skip text

Comment: for example, Done's text change to Finish, and Skip's text change to Cancel

Comment: i dont get you that , what is the error you are getting

Comment: Well, dear friend, is the source code Intro Page. 3 Button is at the bottom of page. I want to change their title. for example, Done's text change to Finish, and Skip's text change to Cancel

Comment: please help me. because very important for me

Comment: i fixed it. tnx dear friend <3